# Check day and do something if it is a workday or weekend

Tags: php

I want to to do something when the day is a workday, and do something else when it is a weekend.

But my function echoes "yes" every time, and I don't get it.

```
var_dump($dag_datumloop);// Saturday is value
if ($dag_datumloop == "Monday" or "Tuesday" or "Wednesday" or "Thursday" or 
"Friday"){
       echo "yes"; 
}else if($dag_datumloop == "Saturday" or "Sunday"){
       echo "no";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current check is only checking to see if `$dag_datumloop` is equal to Monday. The rest are being evaluated on their own.

```
if (($dag_datumloop == "Monday") or ("Tuesday") or ("Wednesday") or ("Thursday") or ("Friday")){
```

The other days would be evaluated as `true` because they're all string values. The easiest way to check it would to be use `in_array` instead of doing `$dag_datumloop ==`  for each one:

```
if(in_array($dag_datumloop, ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']))
```

Comment: Also Luka's is correct, just needed to write if statement correctly like `if($a == 1 || $a == 2)...` and **not** `if($a == 1 || 2 || 3)` cause as aynber mentioned last parst are always `true`

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```php
if (in_array($dag_datumloop, ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'])){
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

you can also use the condition in other way, like:

```php
$isWorkDay = in_array($dag_datumloop, ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];
```

or

```php
echo(in_array($dag_datumloop, ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your if statement like this:

```
<?php 
var_dump($dag_datumloop);// Saturday is value
if ($dag_datumloop == "Monday" or $dag_datumloop == "Tuesday" or $dag_datumloop == "Wednesday" or $dag_datumloop == "Thursday" or $dag_datumloop == "Friday"){
    echo "yes"; 
}else if($dag_datumloop == "Saturday" or $dag_datumloop == "Sunday"){
    echo "no";
}
?>
```